# How to change in Joomla unicode character from database to utf8 string?

Tags: mysql, string, unicode, joomla, user-profile

Joomla saves special characters in database table as unicode chars. For example in the form field from administration panel i have word `wyższe` but in database this word is changed to `wy\u017csze`. When i SELECT this value from database and echo as HTML string , the word still have bad characters in it. The very weird is that in form from administration panel word have correct letter and it appears as `wyższe`. Why when i want print this value via my php code of component (`JFactory::getDbo();`) the unicode style does not want to disappear?

```
        $db = JFactory::getDbo();
        $query = $db->getQuery(true);

        $query->select($db->quoteName('profile_value'))
            ->from($db->quoteName('#__user_profiles'))
            ->where($db->quoteName('profile_key') . ' = "profile.wyksztalcenie"')
            ->where($db->quoteName('user_id') . '=' . (int) $id)
        ;

        $db->setQuery($query);
        $results = $db->loadResult();

        return $results;
```

In administration panel on edit profile page in User Profile tab, word in input text field has the right characters. But when I trying to get a value from the same column for my component, this word still has those unicode characters.

Everything concerns on fields from the User Profile tab. Even if you fill the standard text field, eg `City`, the word is saved in the database with unicode chars. When it is loaded from the database into a text field is converted and the word is correct. The problem occurs when I use Joomla standard queries (see above) to view this values on the subpage of my component. Word is printed still as unicode string. Joomla saves values from text-fields of `User Profile` tab into database as unicode. Why when i want to get this values via standard joomla sql queries, those values are printed still as unicode and not like those when it's done by Joomla?

**IMPORTANT**: One thing. In database values of input text fields are saved with quotation marks but on `User Profile` edit page in administration panel they are loaded without quotation. My sql query print those values with quotation. So the question is. Which file of Joomla installation is responsible for printing text fields in this tab?

**SOLVED**: Those values are saved in database with quotation marks because Joomla on saving convert them into `json` values. So if You want to print those values without quotation marks and without unicode charactes You should to use `return json_decode($results);` instead `return $results;`.

Comment: You say that Joomla stores stuff as Unicode but it seems it's using some non-Unicode encoding such as US-ASCII. What's the collation of your MySQL tables? (Disclaimer: I know nothing about Joomla)

Comment: In this case table has `utf8mb4_unicode_ci` collation. As You see `wy\u017csze` has `\u017c` in it. On [this page](https://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/017c/index.htm) this string is described as "unicode character".

Comment: The page you link describes it as *C/C++/Java source code*. The Unicode character is *ż* ;-) The term *Unicode* must be among the most misused in IT. Whatever, no idea about your problem, sorry.

Comment: MySQL sees `\uxxxx` as 6 ascii characters; it never converts to or from that format and anything else.  The solution must be achieved outside MySQL.